# Java RMI / access denied

Tags: java, security, rmi, policy

I am trying to create an RMI server, but i get the following exception at runtime:

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "localhost:4555" "listen,resolve")
```

I have read the Oracle tutorial about policy files, here's the content of my server.policy file which i inserted into the src folder:

```
grant codeBase "file:///C:/EclipseProjects/MultiServiceServer/src"{

permission java.security.AllPermission;

};
```

I also set VM arguments to:

```
-Djava.security.policy=src/server.policy
```

**Finally, here is the code of this simple RMI server:**

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args)
{       

    System.out.println("Server is running..");

     if (System.getSecurityManager() == null) {
            System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());
     }

    try {

        String name = "AvailableService";

        AvailableService service = new ServiceList();

        AvailableService stub = (AvailableService)UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(service, 0);

        LocateRegistry.createRegistry(4555);

        Registry reg = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(4555);

        reg.bind(name, stub);

        System.out.println(name+" bound");

    } catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}


}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `C:/EclipseProjects/MultiServiceServer/src` folder won't be there at runtime, and doesn't contain .class files at compile time. Granting it any permissions at all is therefore futile. You don't need to use a security manager in RMI at all unless you're using the codebase feature. which you aren't. So remove the security manager.

Comment: If i do not use security manager, i will get another exception (no security manager: RMI classloader disabled) when i trying to work refer from client side to object on the server side. I have read that security manager is required to be able to load classes through RMI.

Comment: The message says `ClassNotFoundException`, and it mentions '(no security manager)' in parentheses as a remark. The *problem* isn't 'no security manager', it is `ClassNotFoundException`. The solution to that isn't to add the security manager, it is to add the missing class into the classpath of the JVM that throws the exception. The security manager is required under the conditions I stated and no others.